# set svg element property asyncronously with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, mathjax

I'm using D3's (v4) TreeLayout to draw an abstract-syntax-tree of a mathematical formula. 
Within some of the nodes I embed other SVG's rendered by MathJax in real-time to display special Math Syntax.

The problem arising is when I want to set the node(circle)-radius in the mainSVG tree based on an asynchronous operation to match the subSVG size?

```
let mainSVG = *appendMainSVG*
...

node.append('circle')
    .attr('r', (d) => {
       CustomES6Class.renderSubSVG(d.data.mathml, (err, subSVG){
         mainSVG.append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
                .html(subSVG);
         const subSVGWidth = subSVG.attr('width');
         ____________________________________________
         I NEED subSVGWidth to be returned to attr(r) 
         but I am inside an async callback
         ____________________________________________
       })
    }
```

I came across d3-queue but the return value of an async operation ends up inside a callback as well...

Any thoughts?

Comment: looks like you lost last `)` and `function` before `(err, subSVG)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why just not use [`each`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_each) and set `r` inside asynchronous call. It, also, save you from, difficult to distinguish, multiline arrow lambda function.

```
node.append('circle')
    .each( function(d){
       CustomES6Class.renderSubSVG(d.data.mathml, function(err, subSVG){
         mainSVG.append('g')
                .attr('transform', `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
                .html(subSVG);
         const subSVGWidth = subSVG.attr('width');
         d3.select( this ).attr( 'r', subSVGWidth );
       }.bind( this ))
    })
```